# SQL Find difference between rows with unique IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table with two rows, one has a start and one an end time with the same id.

For example

```
ID    | Time
12345 | 12-12-18 12:00
12345 | 12-12-18 12:12 
54321 | 12-12-18 11:30
54321 | 12-12-18 11:35
```

How would i go around getting the output

```
ID    | Time
12345 | 12
54321 | 5
```

Guessing Lag or Over?

Comment: If you just have pairs you can self join with same ID and different time.

Comment: Could an ID have more than 2 rows? if so, what is the expected output?

Answer (score 13):

You seem to want an aggregation:

```
select id,
       datediff(minute, min(time), max(time)) as diff_minutes
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking also.

Answer (score 1):

You can also selfjoin as Ezlo also wrote:

```
select a.ID, datediff(minute,MIN(a.time1),max(x.time1) ) as maxtime 
from #test  a inner join #test x on A.id = x.id  group by a.id
```

But seems like Gordons is much simpler :)